# Sitefinity's Default list (mvc) widget disappeared on news details page?

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10

I have to show Listing using the sitefinity's default List widget on my news details page where my list widget disappeared because of news detail's url because my list widget also consider it as details page while I have to show listing only.
To resolve this error I have used the [article](https://blog.falafel.com/lock-content-widgets-urlkeyprefix/) . And this is working fine in case off multiple news widgets i.e one to always display listing and other to display details but same did't work in case of list widget.(I am using mvc widgets for both news and  List,with Sitefinity 10.1.6502.0)

Need your help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like for whatever reason the list widget doesn't implement an override of the [HandleUnknown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.handleunknownaction(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HandleUnknownAction(System.String)) action. (The code for that controller is here: [link](https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather-widgets/blob/master/Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Lists/Mvc/Controllers/ListsController.cs))  You can see similar methods in other widgets that return the index action. (e.g. [the blog post widget](https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather-widgets/blob/9a9c07120d4a2ff9723a86690c4894343dc6d9f6/Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Blogs/Mvc/Controllers/BlogPostController.cs#L249))