# Sitefinity Decompiling Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Lists Dll causing errors

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10, sitefinity-feather

I need to update sitefinity Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Lists dll (version 10.1.6544).
When I decompiled this dll through JustDecomplile Tool, I got tpye error on
**typeof(Tuple).Create** File   \SitefinityFrontendLists\Sitefinity.Frontend.Lists\MVC.Views.Lists\List_AnchorList.cs

Please check this issue and suggest a way to decompile and update sitefinity dlls

```
using Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.WebPages;
using System.Web.WebPages.Instrumentation;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Lists.Mvc.Models;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Mvc.Helpers;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Mvc.Models;

namespace Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Lists.MVC.Views.Lists
{
    [GeneratedCode("RazorGenerator", "2.0.0.0")]
    [PageVirtualPath("~/MVC/Views/Lists/List.AnchorList.cshtml")]
    public class List_AnchorList : WebViewPage<ContentListViewModel>
    {
        public List_AnchorList()
        {
        }

        public override void Execute()
        {
            this.WriteLiteral("\n<div");
            PositionTagged<string> positionTagged = Tuple.Create<string, int>(" class=\"", 194);
            PositionTagged<string> positionTagged1 = Tuple.Create<string, int>("\"", 217);
            AttributeValue[] attributeValueArray = new AttributeValue[] { Tuple.Create<Tuple<string, int>, Tuple<object, int>, bool>(Tuple.Create<string, int>("", 202), Tuple.Create<object, int>(base.Model.CssClass, 202), false) };
            this.WriteAttribute("class", positionTagged, positionTagged1, attributeValueArray);
            this.WriteLiteral(">\n\n");
            foreach (ItemViewModel item in base.Model.Items)
            {
                this.WriteLiteral("        <h1 ");
                this.Write(base.Html.InlineEditingAttributes(base.Model.ProviderName, base.Model.ContentType.FullName, (Guid)((dynamic)item.Fields).Id));
                this.WriteLiteral(">\n            <a");
                this.WriteAttribute("id", Tuple.Create<string, int>(" id=\"", 393), Tuple.Create<string, int>("\"", 417), typeof(Tuple).Create(Tuple.Create<string, int>("", 398), typeof(Tuple).Create<object, int>(((dynamic)item.Fields).Id, 398), false), Tuple.Create<Tuple<string, int>, Tuple<string, int>, bool>(Tuple.Create<string, int>("", 413), Tuple.Create<string, int>("-Top", 413), true));
                this.WriteLiteral("\n               ");
                this.Write(base.Html.InlineEditingFieldAttributes("Title", "ShortText"));
                this.WriteLiteral("\n               href=\"#");
                this.Write(((dynamic)item.Fields).Id);
                this.WriteLiteral("\">");
                this.Write(((dynamic)item.Fields).Title);
                this.WriteLiteral("</a>\n        </h1>\n");
                this.WriteLiteral("        <ul>\n");
                foreach (ItemViewModel itemViewModel in ((ListViewModel)item).ListItemViewModel.Items)
                {
                    this.WriteLiteral("                <li ");
                    this.Write(base.Html.InlineEditingAttributes(base.Model.ProviderName, ((ListViewModel)item).ListItemViewModel.ContentType.FullName, (Guid)((dynamic)itemViewModel.Fields).Id));
                    this.WriteLiteral(">\n                    <a ");
                    this.Write(base.Html.InlineEditingFieldAttributes("Title", "ShortText"));
                    this.WriteLiteral("\n                       href=\"#");
                    this.Write(((dynamic)itemViewModel.Fields).Id);
                    this.WriteLiteral("\">");
                    this.Write(((dynamic)itemViewModel.Fields).Title);
                    this.WriteLiteral("</a>\n                </li>\n");
                }
                this.WriteLiteral("        </ul>\n");
            }
            this.WriteLiteral("\n");
            foreach (ItemViewModel item1 in base.Model.Items)
            {
                this.WriteLiteral("        <h1 ");
                this.Write(base.Html.InlineEditingAttributes(base.Model.ProviderName, base.Model.ContentType.FullName, (Guid)((dynamic)item1.Fields).Id));
                this.WriteLiteral("\n");
                this.WriteLiteral("            ");
                this.Write(base.Html.InlineEditingFieldAttributes("Title", "ShortText"));
                this.WriteLiteral("\n            id=\"");
                this.Write(((dynamic)item1.Fields).Id);
                this.WriteLiteral("\">\n");
                this.WriteLiteral("            ");
                this.Write(((dynamic)item1.Fields).Title);
                this.WriteLiteral("\n        </h1>\n");
                foreach (ItemViewModel itemViewModel1 in ((ListViewModel)item1).ListItemViewModel.Items)
                {
                    this.WriteLiteral("            <div ");
                    this.Write(base.Html.InlineEditingAttributes(base.Model.ProviderName, ((ListViewModel)item1).ListItemViewModel.ContentType.FullName, (Guid)((dynamic)itemViewModel1.Fields).Id));
                    this.WriteLiteral(">\n                <h3 ");
                    this.Write(base.Html.InlineEditingFieldAttributes("Title", "ShortText"));
                    this.WriteLiteral("\n                    id=\"");
                    this.Write(((dynamic)itemViewModel1.Fields).Id);
                    this.WriteLiteral("\">\n");
                    this.WriteLiteral("                    ");
                    this.Write(((dynamic)itemViewModel1.Fields).Title);
                    this.WriteLiteral("\n                </h3>\n\n                <div ");
                    this.Write(base.Html.InlineEditingFieldAttributes("Content", "LongText"));
                    this.WriteLiteral(">");
                    this.Write(base.Html.Raw(((dynamic)itemViewModel1.Fields).Content));
                    this.WriteLiteral("</div>\n\n                <p><a");
                    this.WriteAttribute("href", Tuple.Create<string, int>(" href=\"", 1937), Tuple.Create<string, int>("\"", 1964), Tuple.Create<Tuple<string, int>, Tuple<string, int>, bool>(Tuple.Create<string, int>("", 1944), Tuple.Create<string, int>("#", 1944), true), typeof(Tuple).Create(Tuple.Create<string, int>("", 1945), typeof(Tuple).Create<object, int>(((dynamic)item1.Fields).Id, 1945), false), Tuple.Create<Tuple<string, int>, Tuple<string, int>, bool>(Tuple.Create<string, int>("", 1960), Tuple.Create<string, int>("-Top", 1960), true));
                    this.WriteLiteral(">");
                    this.Write(base.Html.Resource("BackToTop", false));
                    this.WriteLiteral("</a></p>\n            </div>\n");
                }
            }
            this.WriteLiteral("\n</div>\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to decompile? What "update" is needed? How did you invoke JustDecompile, and what are all the exact/full error(s) it gave and implicating which line(s)?

Comment: Sitefinity List widget is dropped on a page where a different detail (news) widget is also present there. So List Widget gets disappeared due to news item URL because List widget also considers it as a detail page. After searching, I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48390374/9612028
Where it is mentioned to add "HandleUnknownAction" on list controller. That's why I am trying to update Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Lists dll (version 10.1.6544).
My current sitefinity version is 10.1.6544.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need to decompile anything. JustDecompile really does as good as it can. But these assemblies are available on GitHub too. https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather-widgets

Comment: Sitefinity List widget is dropped on a page where a different detail (news) widget is also present there. So List Widget gets disappeared due to news item URL because List widget also considers it as a detail page. After searching, I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48390374/9612028
Where it is mentioned to add "HandleUnknownAction" on list controller. That's why I am trying to update Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Lists dll (version 10.1.6544).
My current sitefinity version is 10.1.6544.

Comment: Assembly for Sitefinity 10.1.6544  is not available on GitHub

Comment: No just set the contentviewmode to Master instead of Automatic and it won't react to that url charge.

Comment: I am using MVC Feather List Widget. Where this option is not available.